# Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop DNS Servers

Tags: 18.04, dns

I set DNS servers on my PC to my local DNS caching server (192.168.100.2), and 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1

[image: Wired interface settings - DNS in IPv4 tab]

Resolution on local DNS zone (`.local`) does not work.
It works only when I force dig tool to use local server.

[image: specifying server to dig in command line]

Could you please help me set up a custom DNS server?

Comment: Seems that DNS works in firefox but ping command still cannot resolve my `.local` domain.

Answer (score 2):

My system consists of Ubuntu Desktop and a lot of additional server software, like Bind, Apache, Postfix.
I had the same problem: The configuration network configuration inputs from the GUI (settings > network) did not go into `/etc/resolv.conf`. Also the inputs from `netplan` did not got into `/etc/resolv.conf`. With this solution `dig` and `nslookup` work correctly.

The symbolic link `/etc/resolv.conf` points actually to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`. After the following solution it points to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf 
$ sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```